# Laravel 5.3: hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have the following situation:

```
location
  id - integer
  network_id - integer (FK)

network
  id - integer
  owner_id - integer (FK)

owner
  id - integer
  name - string
```

I have an Eloquent model for my location data. Now what I want to do, is create a RESTful API where I can retrieve the owner data through the network model.

I've tried using `hasManyThrough` with no luck. The model has the following relationships;

```
Network - Location = One to Many
Owner - network = One to One
```

So many locations belong to one network, and each network has one owner. This is always the case.

I've tried the following.

```
class Location extends Model 
{
    public function owner() {
       return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Owner', 'App\Network, 'id', 'id);
    }
}
```

Then return the model in my resource.

```
class LocationController extends Controller 
{
   public function index() {
      return [
         'data' => Location::with('network', 'owner')->take($limit)->take($offset)->get()
      ];
   }
}
```

I don't get an error but the model doesn't return any owner, instead just an empty array.

Can anybody help me out creating a relationship between those models using Laravel's Eloquent? I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what problems arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether your table structure fits to be able to use hasManyThrough

From what I can see with the documentation you would need

```
location
  id - integer
  network_id - integer

network
  id - integer
  location_id - integer

owner
  id - integer
  network_id - integer
  name - string
```

Then you could use

```
 return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Owner', 'App\Network',
            'location_id', 'network_id', 'id'
        );
```

That being said you may be able to get it to work by trying different combinations the hasManyThrough e.g.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Owner', 'App\Network, 'owner_id', 'id', 'network_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

bind relationship with below code

```
class Location extends Model
{
 public function network()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Network');
 }
}


class Network extends Model
{

 public function owner()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Owner');
 }
}
```

it solved your problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Owner Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Owner extends Model
{    

    public function get_data()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location','App\Network');
    }  

}
```

**Call Model:**

```
<?php

$data=Owner::find(1)->get_data()->select('network_id','location_id')->get();
```

=> Get network and location table data to use select option